# ThreadPool.SetMinThreads under .NET compact framework 3.5

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, threadpool

I think I have an issue that will require me to raise the minimum threads allocated in the threadpoll under a .NET CF application running under Windows CE.

It appears that this method isn't implemented on the compact framework. Is there any way for me to recreate that method call under the compact framework? A registry or system setting perhaps?

Comment: You could add a MinTreadCount and MaxTreadCount into your app.config in a section that your Service can read.

Comment: Once I read it from the app.config, what method do I call to set the value. The SetMinThreads method isn't available in the Compact framework

Comment: if you set something like  const int DefaultMinThreads = 5; const int DefaultMaxThreads = 10; I am sure you will not hit the min/max on ce.

Comment: Found this --> The number of threads is only limited by the available system resources. That is a fancy way of saying that when the system runs out of physical RAM, no more threads can be started. So min thread is Limited By System Resources. I would just add some exception handling where you spin a new worker and check for ...Out of Memory!

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about manually managing my own threads. I'm talking about the System.Threading.ThreadPool class.

Comment: You will have to fix your problem without it, CF doesn't have a way to configure it.  This isn't exactly a very appropriate bandaid on desktops either, you'd only ever consider increasing min threads when the tp threads are blocking too much.  A proper fix is to use a regular Thread instead of the pool.

Comment: I'm not using the threadpool at all in my usercode. However I suspect that one or more third party libraries I'm using are making use of the threadpool and causing havok when I'm using form.BeginInvoke.

Comment: I was not aware the `Control.BeginInvoke` utilized the ThreadPool?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you saying that the method isn't implemented on .Net Compact Framework.
The official MSDN documentation said that you can set static property SetMaxThreads on the ThreadPool class :

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms172522(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms172522%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Paolo.